# responseText array not parsing properly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, responsetext

I'm using ajax to retrieve an json_encode() array from my php parser.

The responseText is `["4.wav","2.wav","3.wav","6.mp3","1.mp3","5.wav"]`

If I place this in and array like this:

```
var myArray = ["4.wav","2.wav","3.wav","6.mp3","1.mp3","5.wav"];
```

myArray will return

```
4.wav, 2.wav, 3.wav, 6.mp3, 1.mp3, 5.wav
```

with an myArray.length count of 6 as expected right?

But if I place my responseText in a var and like this:

```
var myArray = event.target.responseText;
```

myArray will return

`["4.wav","2.wav","3.wav","6.mp3","1.mp3","5.wav"]`

and an myArray.length count of 49.

Can someone kindly explain what the heck is going on here?

Here is how I made the ajax call:

```
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ajax.addEventListener("load", function(event){  
    var response = event.target.responseText;});

    ajax.open("POST", "parser.php");
    ajax.send();
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try to use JSON.parse to your response text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Javascript function `JSON.parse()` with your given response.

```
var a = '["4.wav","2.wav","3.wav","6.mp3","1.mp3","5.wav"]';
alert(JSON.parse(a).length);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2p6yve9d/)**

Answer (score 4):

Because `event.target.responseText` isn't an array, it's a string. The length of a string object refers to the amount of characters in a string. You will need to call a `JSON.parse` on your response to get it in the correct format you want.

```
var responseText = '["4.wav","2.wav","3.wav","6.mp3","1.mp3","5.wav"]';

responseText.length //49 at this point, the length of the string

var responseArray = JSON.parse(responseText);

responseArray.length //6, because it's an array
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind,
I found the solution.

if I use

`var myArray= JSON.parse(ajaxResponse);`

The return will be

`4.wav, 2.wav, 3.wav, 6.mp3, 1.mp3, 5.wav`

So I can use it as an array.

Lol, my first question in StackOverflow and I answered it my slef! :P